# How to check the value currently shown in select within a Cypress test

Tags: cypress

I have a select that shows the value "select me" if the user has not yet selected an option. "select me" is not actually an option in the select, its just the default value shown.

So how can I check that value?

Something like this doesn't work because "select me" is not an option:

```javascript
cy.get('#filter-dropdown').find('option:selected').should('contain.text', 'select me');
```

Comment: Hard to say what may help without an HTML sample to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by finding the label for the select since the label is what contains the text, whether its defaulted or selected.

```
cy.get('label[for="filter-dropdown"]').should('contain.text', 'select me');
```